# Simplifying lets and ifs in a JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of vars(let), each one of them connects to a tag that is going to be replaced and decide if the element is visible or not. if the tag replaced has any text at all it is going to be visible, if it dont have any, its going to change the element class to one that has a `display:none;`. I just cant believe there isnt any way to make this simplier, but i cant think of none, also if you have any tips in simplyfing ifs or vars feel free to give them. Thank you for the attention.

```
let visib1= "#product1#";
let visib2= "#product2#";
let visib3= "#product3#";
let visib4= "#product4#";
let visib5= "#product5#";
let visib6= "#product6#";
let visib7= "#product7#";
let visib8= "#product8#";
let visib9= "#product9#";

if(!visib1){
    document.getElementById('product1').classList.add("invisivel");
}

if(!visib2){
    document.getElementById('product2').classList.add("invisivel");
}

if(!visib3){
    document.getElementById('product3').classList.add("invisivel");
}

if(!visib4){
    document.getElementById('product4').classList.add("invisivel");
}

if(!visib5){
    document.getElementById('product5').classList.add("invisivel");
}

if(!visib6){
    document.getElementById('product6').classList.add("invisivel");
}

if(!visib7){
    document.getElementById('product7').classList.add("invisivel");
}

if(!visib8){
    document.getElementById('product8').classList.add("invisivel");
}

if(!visib9){
    document.getElementById('product9').classList.add("invisivel");
}
```

the html part:

```
<body>
<div class="text" id="product1">
      <p>new</p>
</div>
<div class="disccount" id="product2">
      <p>disccount</p>
</div>
<div class="text" id="product3">
      <p>new</p>
</div>
<div class="disccount" id="product4">
      <p>disccount</p>
</div>
<div class="text" id="product5">
      <p>new</p>
</div>
<div class="disccount" id="product6">
      <p>disccount</p>
</div>
<div class="text" id="product7">
      <p>new</p>
</div>
<div class="disccount" id="product8">
      <p>disccount</p>
</div>
<div class="text" id="product9">
      <p>new</p>
</div>
</body>
```

its an example html

Comment: The easiest route would be to use an array, a for loop, and build your id/class name based on your loop var

Comment: why do you assign a string to variables and use the boolena value of it?

Comment: do you happen to know any tutorial about that ?

Comment: its a system that is going to decide if these are going to be visible or not, and the system can only change string variables between those ##

Comment: please add the html part as well to the question plus a use case for it.

Comment: @NinaScholz Testing a string variable as a boolean is a way to test if the string is set and non-empty.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, i know it, but why a string if no reason?

Comment: I added an html

Comment: Your if condition doesn't make any sense. It's  value is a string that is the ID of an element. Dies the value of these variables change?

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead of lots of separate variables.

```
let visib = ["#product1#", "#product2#"];
visib.forEach(v => {
    let m = v.match(/#product(\d+)#/);
    let num = m[1];
    document.getElementById(`product${num}`).classList.add('invisivel');
});
```

Comment: i fount it a bit difficult to understand since i'm new to JavaScript but it seems really helpfull, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could query for multiple selectors and add the class to each item in the resulting element list.

```js
const invisible = ["#product-1", "#product-3", "#product-5", "#product-7", "#product-9"];

document.querySelectorAll(invisible.join(', '))
  .forEach(el => el.classList.add('invisible'));
```

```css
.invisible { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="product" id="product-1"><p>Product 1</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-2"><p>Product 2</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-3"><p>Product 3</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-4"><p>Product 4</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-5"><p>Product 5</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-6"><p>Product 6</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-7"><p>Product 7</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-8"><p>Product 8</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-9"><p>Product 9</p></div>
```

To reverse this, you would need a common class to access them:

```js
const visible = ["#product-2", "#product-4", "#product-6", "#product-8" ];

document.querySelectorAll('.product')
  .forEach(el =>
    el.classList.toggle('invisible', !visible.includes(`#${el.id}`)));
```

```css
.invisible { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="product" id="product-1"><p>Product 1</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-2"><p>Product 2</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-3"><p>Product 3</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-4"><p>Product 4</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-5"><p>Product 5</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-6"><p>Product 6</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-7"><p>Product 7</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-8"><p>Product 8</p></div>
<div class="product" id="product-9"><p>Product 9</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply like this:

```
for (let i=1;i<10;i++) {
 let d=document.getElementById('product'+i); 
 if (!d.textContent.trim()) d.classList.add('invisivel');
}
```

This will test each div for text content and will assign the class "invisible" if there is no text inside. The `.trim()` call makes sure that a div containing only blanks is treated as "empty".